# DB2 Stored Procedure IF/ELSE -- What am I missing?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

Trying to modify a stored procedure at work and looking to add some conditional logic into the procedure.  I created a small test procedure just to try and understand IF/ELSE logic and I keep getting barked at by DBeaver (my SQL UI).  I took the example pretty much directly off an IBM documentation web site.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IFTEST(IN rating INTEGER, OUT res VARCHAR(1))
  LANGUAGE  SQL
  BEGIN
    IF rating = 1 THEN
        SET res = '2';
   -- ELSE IF rating = 2 THEN
    --  SET res = 3;
    ELSE
        SET res = '4';
    END IF;
  END
```

It keeps giving me this:

```
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "s = '4'".  Expected tokens may include:  " 
    END IF".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

Comment: Configure the statement delimiter in Dbeaver to be something different than the default semi-colon, many people use @ instead. Then use that chosen character after the end of the block (i.e. after the final END)..   This is a FAQ, so do your research, because many asked this same question before.

Comment: In my experience, DBeaver behaves strangely in many situations using the db2 jdbc connector. Sometimes I think there is some issue with the jdbc itself. I could give many examples that could be consideres as a bug.

Comment: Thanks @mao. For the record I've been scouring the net for a solution before posting.  Changed the delimiter and now I'm getting this:

  SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequently asked question.

First ensure your code is syntactically valid: in your case verify that each conditional statement has its own `END IF`, or alternatively use `ELSEIF` (and not `ELSE IF`) when you want to have a single conditional statement.

Next, verify your compound statement delimiters.

When you have a 'block' (multiple SQL statements) that executes as a single-statement (also known as compound SQL compiled), the Db2 client tool needs to recognize the end of the block.

The SQL standard does not specify how to do this, so different RDBMS tools use different techniques.

Many people who use Db2 will use the @ character as the compound SQL block  delimiter instead of the default character which is semi-colon.  That semi-colon is still required to delimit the statements inside of the block, but the block also needs to have some delimiter, so if you use @ then the final character in your stored-procedure should be that @ character.  You then select the block including this delimiter and ask DBeaver to execute it as a single compound statement.

DBeaver lets you do this configuration via its settings GUI.

Example navigation in DBeaver (depending on your version of DBeaver):

Properties > Editors > SQL Editor > SQL Processing

```
Statements delimiter:  @
Ignore native delimiter (tick)
Blank line is statement delimiter (only use this if you code accordingly)
Remove trailing query delimiter (tick)
```

When you make these changes, you make need to disconnect the data source, and reconnect before they will be effective.

You can also make these changes in 'Global Settings' if you only use Db2 data sources and want these settings for all databases.
But again, you may need to disconnect and reconnect before the settings become effective.

Comment: I appreciate your responses. I made all the changes you suggested above and I'm still seeing the error. Are there other settings in DBeaver that might be causing this?      
        New procedure: CREATE PROCEDURE IFTEST(IN rating INTEGER, OUT res VARCHAR(1)) LANGUAGE SQL BEGIN IF rating = 1 THEN SET res = '2'; ELSE IF rating = 2 THEN SET res = 3; ELSE SET res = '4'; END IF; END @                       Error: SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END" was found following "'". Expected tokens may include: " END IF".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: My bad.  Yup, I had fat-fingered the space between the ELSE and IF and that was causing the fail.  Now it executes OK.  I think my main problem was just the DBeaver delimeter issue.  Thanks again!